# Why images are hidden in React initialized with VITE?

Tags: reactjs, image, vite

I have a problem with Vite. I am transitioning from CRA to Vite, but the main issue is that I can't see my pictures initialized in the `background-image` URL.
When i import.

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to right bottom, rgba($color-dark-light, 0.5), rgba($color-dark, 0.8)), url(../../assets/img/DrunkMan.png);
```

When I import them like this: `import logo from '../assets/img/logoPosilnovanie.png'`, they will show up, but not from my SCSS.

```
import logo from '../assets/img/DrunkMan.png';
```

I will send a picture what i have after inspecting and the pictures are available on click !

[image: Inspecting element]

Initially, I thought that the issue might be related to my devDependencies, such as Sass and others, but it turns out that they are all set up correctly. Additionally, the vite.config.js file doesn't seem to be causing the problem either. What's interesting is that the visual effects are functioning properly despite the issue I'm experiencing.
I have also tried to play with relative paths but not worked.

Comment: Are these images in `/public ` folder?

Comment: @Konrad its a Vite. I have it in assets under img folder....

Comment: https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html

Comment: Are you not able to access image in SCSS? In your image is applied but may be hidden.

Comment: @Konrad Thanms for documentation i will read that.

Comment: @sahilatahar I mean when i set the url( path ) ... so the absolute path is okay. I can click on it and it will navigate to the picture. But its not working in a browser.

Comment: @JakubGaba I tried to add image using sass file and it is working properly. Add some code in the question and also the folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

Alright i found the problem guys.
[image: react helmet and styles.scss]

Here you can see i am setting up html font size two times and here is what it did.

[image: html font size]

It ignored the @media max width so all i had to do is to delete html font size from react helmet... ahh

**The styles what are being injecting via React Helmet are being placed directly into the HTML document as is. They are not being preprocessed by SCSS or any other preprocessor. This means they don't understand or parse SCSS mixins or variables.**